# Boolean state react

Tags: reactjs

what is the best approach?

i need a boolean to use in a button and the result of this boolean i already have in a state of menuPosition.

```
  const [menuPosition, setMenuPosition] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
```

I thought creating a new state:

```
 const [open, setOpen} = useState<Boolean>(false)
```

but, i could also derivate from the state that already had instanced:

```
const open = Boolean(menuPosition)
```

or a i ccould just put in my component argument:

```
Boolean(menuPosition)
```

This could help me not declaring more code but this will not be very legible right? Specialy if a needed to use it in more than one place...

thinking about perfomance, memory use and readbilty, what is the best option?

the deravation, creating a new state or using just the Boolean(menuPosition) directly into the component?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to declare a regular variable in the component's body. You don't need `useState`, since it is entirely depending on the `menuPosition`.
The simplest way:

```
const isOpen = !!menuPosition;
```

You can also consider using [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) to store the value, however, I wouldn't say that this is necessary since it is just a primitive and isn't pricey to calculate:

```
const isOpen = useMemo(() -> !!menuPosition, [menuPosition]);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! if i choose the first option: isOpen will be a const derivating from a state. How is gonna be the behavior of this const? It is a const, so we cannot update his value, so every time that the state changes, the const will be recriated?

Comment: Yes, but it is just a `bit` in the memory, 0 or 1, so I wouldn't worry much about this. If you will have any other actions like click, .etc in that case you would need the useState

Answer (score 0):

Since open will not trigger any render in your screen, you'll not need to use a state. Furthermore, as you already have a value for `Boolean` casting and this value is a state, you just need to cast this by adding "!" before the variable, like the following:

```js
const open = !menuPosition;
```

Another tip: you mustn't use `Boolean` to type a primitive value in typescript, use `boolean`, with lowercase, instead. You can see more about primitive types here [Typescript Everyday Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html).

Since this code is a pretty basic one, I think you are over engineering by thinking so much in performance and memory in this situation.

Comment: It should be `!!menuPosition`, not the negation

Comment: It can be both. The way you will use that will define.

Comment: the OP has the boolean version of the truthy `menuPosition`, not the negation